# Identification of white flower with four petals

Tags: identification, flowers, weeds

Just wondering what this is. Found it in an old pot out back and not sure if I should toss or save. TIA

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer below. Does the distribution of this species match your location?

Comment: @Samantha If you think it's the right answer (I think it is), it's helpful to mark it as accepted (the check mark  under the voting arrows). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's in the family Rubiaceae. [*Diodia virginiana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diodia_virginiana) looks like a good match.